# change color of image to greyscale in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a png image which I want to convert into grey scale. I managed to convert it into greyscale however it also changes the color for transparent ares of the image. **How can I change its color without changing the transparent area of the image?**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'image.png';
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 420, 420);
var px = imageData.data;

var len = px.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i+=4) {
    var redPx = px[i];
    var greenPx = px[i+1];
    var bluePx = px[i+2];
    var alphaPx = px[i+3];

    var greyScale = redPx * .3 + greenPx * .59 + bluePx * .11;

    px[i] = greyScale;
    px[i+1] = greyScale;
    px[i+2] = greyScale;
    px[i+3] = greyScale;
}

ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Although it's not fully supported, in chrome you can use `-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alpha is "not a color". You should copy it as it is, leaving the transparent part transparent. Just remove the line:

```
px[i+3] = greyScale;
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not fully sure about purpose of this, but since the question is also tagged "HTML5" I assume it might be needed for purposes different than e.g. image manipulation library. If that's not some kind of an image editor or HTML5 game, and you just need to convert some of your images to grayscale e.g. on hover, you may as well use CSS:

```
.grayscale {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
}
```

If that's not suitable, please post more information about why do you need to do this

Comment: +1 to this answer, since although is not answering the exact question, the solution provided is more standard-friendly than the original problem itself.

Answer (score 0):

this plugin (tancolor.js) does the similar thing that you want to achieve, you can try to check the [source code](https://github.com/nicolaisi/tancolor) and there's an [intractive demo](http://nicolaisi.github.io/tancolor/) for you to test things out.